# I Can't Write Anything in Autocompletetextview and not displaying a virtual keyboard

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I used `Fragmentpageradapter` and out of this one fragment used `autocompletetextview` but i can't able to write anything or does not show keyboard on click on `autocompletetextview`.

Source :

**layout_autocompleteTextview :**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel_seacrh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/edt_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text=""
            android:imeOptions="actionGo|flagNoExtractUi"

            android:background="@drawable/search_background"
            android:hint="Search Category" />
        <requestFocus/>
```

Fragment that i am used the autocomplete textview

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
            manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

          // Context c = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            this.context = container.getContext();

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

            categoryGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_category_item);
            rel_search = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rel_seacrh);
            edt_search = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edt_search);


        adapterCategory = new CategoryListAdapter(this.context, categoryData.getCategoryItems());
        this.categoryGridView.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
        this.categoryGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new CategoryItemClickListener());
        for (int i=0; i<categoryData.getCategoryItems().size(); i++)
        {
            item.add(categoryData.getCategoryItems().get(i).getName());
        }

        //Create adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item);

        edt_search.setThreshold(1);

        //Set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView
        edt_search.setAdapter(adapter);
        edt_search.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        edt_search.setOnItemClickListener(this);
return rootview;
}
```

}

**Image :**

[image: Image of autocomplete textview]

Comment: didi you check it on real device

Comment: Yes I m check in real device.

Comment: Try to remove _flagNoExtractUi_ from xml

Comment: Hello @JollyRaiyani how Did you solve it? I'm also facing the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in manifest file,

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

Comment: keyboard is open but i can't able to write.can't display text or edited the text.i am used autocompletetextview in fragment pageadapter.

Comment: Tried changing text color of the AutoCompleteTextView?